# RabbitMQ get queue data does not add header data. any idea how to get it

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqadmin

rabbitmqadmin get queue=test requeue=false print below response

```
+-------------+----------+---------------+--------------+------------------+-------------+  
| routing_key | exchange | message_count |   payload    | payload_encoding | redelivered |  
+-------------+----------+---------------+--------------+------------------+-------------+  
| test        |          | 0             | hello, world | string           | False       |  
+-------------+----------+---------------+--------------+------------------+-------------+
```

I want to get header as one more columns and its value.

How I can get it header value in the above table. If not possible in the same table then how to get it in other table. I want to publish my header data also with response data

Answer (score 1):

Just use --depth.

**Example without --depth:** rabbitmqadmin get queue=smsc01 requeue=true count=10

Result without headers:

```
> +-------------+----------+---------------+---------+---------------+------------------+-------------+
> | routing_key | exchange | message_count | payload | payload_bytes | payload_encoding | redelivered |
> +-------------+----------+---------------+---------+---------------+------------------+-------------+
> | empty       | smsc-ex  | 4             | empty1  | 6             | string           | True        |
> | empty       | smsc-ex  | 3             | empty2  | 6             | string           | True        |
> | empty       | smsc-ex  | 2             | empty3  | 6             | string           | True        |
> | empty       | smsc-ex  | 1             | empty3  | 6             | string           | True        |
> | empty       | smsc-ex  | 0             | empty4  | 6             | string           | True        |
> +-------------+----------+---------------+---------+---------------+------------------+-------------+
```

**Example with --depth:** rabbitmqadmin get queue=smsc01 requeue=true count=10 --depth=4

Result with headers:

```
> +-------------+----------+---------------+---------+---------------+------------------+--------------------------+---------------------------+-------------+
> | routing_key | exchange | message_count | payload | payload_bytes | payload_encoding | properties.delivery_mode | properties.headers.msisdn | redelivered |
> +-------------+----------+---------------+---------+---------------+------------------+--------------------------+---------------------------+-------------+
> | empty       | smsc-ex  | 4             | empty1  | 6             | string           | 2                        |                           | True        |
> | empty       | smsc-ex  | 3             | empty2  | 6             | string           | 2                        |                           | True        |
> | empty       | smsc-ex  | 2             | empty3  | 6             | string           | 2                        |                           | True        |
> | empty       | smsc-ex  | 1             | empty3  | 6             | string           | 2                        |                           | True        |
> | empty       | smsc-ex  | 0             | empty4  | 6             | string           | 2                        | 48654987321               | True        |
> +-------------+----------+---------------+---------+---------------+------------------+--------------------------+---------------------------+-------------+
```